# Convenient way to use gpg on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I am using cloud based email (e.g. gmail and hotmail) and some of my contacts want me to encrypt the emails I send.

On my linux desktop, I can use gpg, save the armored text to a file and copy paste it as plain text into the email.

I was wondering if there is something similar available on Ubuntu phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gpg is available in the terminal app by default on Ubuntu touch so you shouldn't have to change your process. I use it to store my password for websites.

E.g. http://www.softwareontheside.info/2016/05/using-gpg-as-last-pass-alternative.html